# Do you know any scenario involving Yog-Sothoth?

Tags: published-adventures, call-of-cthulhu

I am looking for a published Call of Cthulhu campaign or at least a scenario involving the Yog-Sothoth or his cult. Well known Shadows of Yog-Sothoth campaign, despite its name, resolves more around Cthulhu than the titular great old one.